# Different Reminder/task In same imap email account, client outlook 365 and calendar synced with caldav syncronizer

Tags: email, sync, imap, microsoft-outlook-365, caldav

I set up a Qboxmail with IMAP and CalDav, configuring that email on two different Outlook 365 clients (fully updated). I used CalDav Synchronizer to sync the calendar between the two Outlook 365 clients, but, the reminders/task list is different between the two clients after a week.

- Is there a way to sync those items, and how do Tasks get synched via IMAP?
- Should I use Qboxmail with ExchangeActiveSync to synch the tasks?

Comment: Please use basic writing formats, such as paragraphs, bullets, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In This scenario, CalDav Synchronizer Is correctly synching the EVENTS in the calendar.
The Reminder or Task in calendar Event IS part of the EVENTS and so it is synched between computers when the EVENTS are Synched.